# String literal and macro concatenation in preprocessor

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, string-literals

FINAL UPDATE:

After reading many related questions and answers it seems to me the answer is simple, albeit disappointing: It is impossible to concatenate string literals in preprocessor. Adding macro to the mix does not change this, it only muddles the picture.

I'll delete this question later, unless somebody says the above is wrong.

================

I am trying to define a string literal from several string literals and some macros.

Yes, **I know that adjacent string literals are concatenated by the compiler**. There are hundreds of questions "how to concatenate strings in preprocessor" here and they all have pretty much [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188570/10627427). But it does not answer the actual question.

I am trying to do something like this (the code below is just a hint, it needs a second layer of parameterized macro to actually compile)

```
#define A 1
#define B 2

#define STR1 "Up\r" #A "\r" #B "\r"
#define STR2 "Down\r" #B "\r" #A "\r"

char* strings[] = { STR1, STR2 };
```

In this example, when I examine STR1 macro expansion in IDE, I would like to see `"Up\r1\r2\r"`, not `"Up\r" "1" "\r" "2" "\r"`.

UPDATE:

The example below shows that IDE is perfectly capable of displaying merged macro, in this case macro expansion on STR1 shows "12". It is only when I am trying to add string literals to the mix I am having problems.

```
#define CON1(a,b) a ## b
#define CON2(a,b) CON1(a,b)
#define STR1 CON2(A,B)
```

My question is this: Is it possible to concatenate strings and macros in preprocessor to get final string literal as one unbroken string?

Comment: Why is it important what the IDE shows?

Comment: I don't think the pre-processor is concatenating string literals - I think that's done by the compiler.  `#define x 2 * 3`, I don't think x will show up as 6.

Comment: `"Up\r" "1" "\r" "2" "\r"` *is*  the macro expansion. Concatenation happens later.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat because unlike the heavily oversimplified example in the question, the real program has dozens of macros and long literals combined into dozens of strings. It is real pain to debug without seeing the actual result of concatenation.

Comment: @molbdnilo I thought highlighting the second line would be enough to show that I know that much...

Comment: To be clear - this code is performing correctly, but you are asking how to change the behavior of your IDE?  Is that correct?

Comment: Fortunately, the string to obtain is indeed `"Up\r" "1" "\r" "2" "\r"`, to evaluate and results as the concatenation of that. Trying to replace `\r` by its equivalent `\12`, the result is `"Up\12" "1" "\12" "2" "\12"` which is same and fine, but `"Up\121\122\12"` seen as `"UpQR\r"` is not!

Comment: At least in VS `constexpr char X[] = "a" "b" "c";` would show up as `constexpr const char X[4] = "abc";` so consider using `constexpr` instead of macros or alternatively assign those you need to inspect to `constexpr` variables...

Comment: @fabian Thank you for trying to answer my actual question. Unfortunately, in STM32 IDE it still shows original string components.

Comment: `#define STR1 "Up\r" #A "\r" #B "\r"` [is not legal C++ code](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.stringize). `#` can only be applied to macro parameters, of which `STR1` doesn't have any.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit You are correct. That code shows what I am _trying_ to do. The working code looks like this: _#define STR(p1,p2,...) "Up\r" TOSTR(p1) "\r" ..._ and then _#define STR1 STR(A,B,...)_

Comment: This question may get answered sometime in the future, helping future visitors to the site.  That's the purpose of these questions and this site.  I recommend _not_ deleting this question simply because it is no longer suiting you.  Likewise, if you think you know the answer, you may post it as an answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann OK, I'll leave it here. Although I suspect it will be deleted eventually anyway, after being downvoted a dozen times.

Comment: I think this is a good and valid question. To my knowledge, this isn't possible,  without weird #include/file system hacks.

Comment: I suppose one thing that you could do is use a `#define STR(...) #__VA_ARGS__` macro to declare your string constants (this can e.g. mess up whitespace). Then you could use something like `#define STRe(...) STR(__VA_ARGS__) #define DELMR_STR(...) __VA_ARGS__ #define STRCAT(a,b)  STR_(DELME_##a, DELME_##b)` to concatenate the literals lazily. (with `#define DELMR_STR(...) __VA_ARGS__`) This should make `STRCAT(STR(a b),STR(c d))` expand to "a b c d", but you'd have to be careful that the STR isn't expanded before you pass it to STRCAT.

Comment: @camel-cdr I did not try that, it might just work. But consider this - when you have a dozen combinations of a dozen parameters in different order with different literals between them making macro like that will get out of hand pretty soon. It might be easier to simply use sprintf() and examine resulting strings in debug mode. Also, I believe this won't work with things like "\r"

Comment: I vote to keep it - I think my answer is satisfactory. I don't understand the negativism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** Concatenation of adjacent string literals occurs in [Phase 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases#Phase_6), while preprocessing occurs in [Phase 4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases#Phase_4).

You did not mention which IDE you were using, but you could submit a feature request that expanded macros optionally have their strings concatenated. It should not be the default option, however, because then the IDE would be lying to you about what the macros precisely expand to.

Comment: The fact that it does not work I've already accepted. Thank you for providing an explanation why. I am using STM32CubeIDE, which is basically Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html)?

```c
#include <cstdio>

#define A 1
#define B 2

#define XSTR(A) #A
#define STR(A) XSTR(A)

#define STR1 "Up\n" STR(A) "\n" STR(B) "\n"

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", STR1);
  return 0;
}
```

On my Ubuntu 20, it prints:

```
Up
1
2
```

Comment: This, of course works. The problem, however, is that evaluated STR1 macro is a sequence of string literals, not one combined string.